# check the image source having image or not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel-5.4

I need to hide the div when the image source have an image(that image from an server side) if there is not image need to hide the div in jquery

This is my html file

```
<div class="form-group bc-my-group">
     <label>Photo Upload</label>
     <div class="input-group image-preview">
         <input id="imageToUpload" class="form-control image-preview-filename" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="images" />
         <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group bc-my-group">
     <label>My Photo</label>
     <div id="prof_image">
          <img src ="{{ asset($profile) }}">
     </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone give me an idea to obtain this??

Comment: Just check @if($profile) and have your div inside that if

Comment: check my answer below .you can  do it via jquery.

Comment: @AyatullahRahmani thank you will check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use the onerror event in JavaScript to act when an image fails
>   to load:

```
 var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    img.onerror = function () { 
        this.style.display = "none";
    }
```

> In jQuery (since you asked):

```
 $("#myImg").error(function () { 
        $(this).hide(); 
    });
```

> Or for all images:

```
$("img").error(function () { 
    $(this).hide();
    // or $(this).css({visibility:"hidden"}); 
});
```

You should use visibility: hidden instead of .hide() if hiding the images might change the layout. Many sites on the web use a default "no image" image instead, pointing the src attribute to that image when the specified image location is unavailable.

> for your solution just use this

```
 $("#prof_image img").error(function () { 
   $(this).parent().hide(); 
 });
```

Comment: Can you give the code more clearly what i want to give this in my code

Comment: this should be work . any way whats code you apply??

Comment: ` var img = document.getElementById("upload");
      img.onerror = function () { 
          this.style.display = "none";
      }
      $("#prof_image img").error(function () { 
        $(this).parent().hide(); 
      });`

Comment: the myimg denoted which id

Comment: $("#prof_image img").error(function () {   $(this).parent().hide();  }); Use this in document.ready

Comment: or remove id and use class instead of id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144215/discussion-between-karthiga-and-ayatullah-rahmani).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript:

**CSS:**

```
.div {
display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.image').onload = function() {
    // image exists and is loaded
    $('.div').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier if you specify which div you want to hide when you have and image and which one you want to hide when there is no image, I guess you want to hide the div with the photo upload if you already have an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Laravel template by checking source and add a class named as `hide` like,

```
{{ asset($profile)==''?'hide':'' }}
```

Code,

```
<div class="form-group bc-my-group {{ asset($profile)==''?'hide':'' }}">
     <label>Photo Upload</label>
     <div class="input-group image-preview">
         <input id="imageToUpload" class="form-control image-preview-filename" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" name="images" />
         <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

In **CSS**, create a class like,

```
.hide{display:none !important;}
```

Comment: Inspect your div element in your browser's console for the class `hide` and make sure you have added `hide` class in your CSS file.

Comment: And what about class `hide` in your div element, check it in your browser's console.

Comment: try this - {{ asset($profile)==' '?'class="hide"':' ' }}

Comment: when i inspect the div it doesnot show the hide element

Comment: What you are getting in `asset($profile)` when the src is not available, you can change your condition according to it.

Comment: @AyatullahRahmani `class` is already applied to that element and hence no need of it.

Comment: i want to hide the div when the source `asset($profile)` is not available

Comment: If the source is not available then what value is returned by the function `asset($profile)`.